# Text input with Autocomplete for facets field in search page using solr search api?

Tags: ajax, search

As my terms and values for multi-valued fields are growing, search page is taking too much time to load all values under facet filter. In order to improve the performance and give better User experience i would like to have a text input box as filter instead of facets check boxes,links and select list. So whenever user types any text in the text box,system should auto-suggest only matched facet values based on the current search result and when any item item is selected from the list, respective filter should be applied.

With this above implementation approach performance will be improved and user can easily search and apply their desired filters.

(OR)

In other words i need a text based search filter like Zomato's location filter using facets with solr search api. 
Please Visit: https://www.zomato.com/bangalore/restaurants for reference.